# Including a foreign function in you own R package's source code

Tags: r, r-package

I am currently facing the following situation: in an `R` package I am developing I am using two functions from the `tidytext` package. Thus, currently `tidytext` is part of the `Imports` in my `DESCRIPTION` file. The 'problem' is that `tidytext` has a lot of dependencies whereas I would like to keep the dependencies of my package low. In fact the two functions from `tidytext` I am using rely solely on the `base` package.

Therefore, I am wondering if its OK to simply **include these functions in my own package's source code**? I would not export them as they are only 'helpers' for some user facing functions. Is there any issue with this approach (thinking of licenses for example)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tidytext` is [published with a MIT licence](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidytext/index.html) which grants you the following rights [emphasis is mine]:

> Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining
>   a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the
>   "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including
>   without limitation the rights to use, **copy**, modify, merge, publish,
>   distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to
>   permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to
>   the following conditions:

**But** you have to follow this:

> The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be
>   included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

As long as you do this you should be fine

## Edit:

[related SE question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/234437/bsd-mit-license-changes-when-copy-pasting-a-function-from-another-bsd-mit-licens)

Comment: The **But** basically mean I would have to use the MIT license, too?

Comment: I don't think so, [see this post](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/5700/is-using-mit-licensed-code-in-non-open-source-code-considered-stealing) and I don't see any mention of this requirement in the licence. It only says that you must **include** the original MIT (pertaining to the copied code) licence with your code